# Vb.Net XmlDeseralize xml attributes into class object

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization, deserialization

I am having trouble deserializing xml attributes into class properties.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<Ball clientid="xyz">
    <Name>Tommy</Name>
    <ballColor transactionid="1234">White</ballColor>
    <radius>9</radius>
    <PowerLevel>9001</PowerLevel>
    <RandomProp>This is another property</RandomProp>
</Ball>
```

Is the XML i am using... and now I will post the code I have. The thing is I am able to get the clientid into the property, but not the 'transactionid' So I am having trouble pulling out the attribute of a child element

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Public Class Ball
    Inherits ballColor
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property radius As Double
    Public Property PowerLevel As String
    Public Property RandomProp As String
    <XmlAttribute("clientid")> Public Property clientid() As String


    Public Sub New()

    End Sub


End Class
<XmlRoot("Ball")>
Public Class ballColor
    <XmlElement("ballColor")> Public Property ballColor As String
    <XmlAttribute("transactionid")> Public Property transactionid As String
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

So I have the actual deserialize call on a form but that doesn't seem to be my issue because when I run this, literally every property gets filled correctly besides the transactionid. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather have ballColor as a property within ball. Try this below.

```
<Serializable>
<XmlRoot("Ball")>
Public Class Ball
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property radius As Double
    Public Property PowerLevel As String
    Public Property RandomProp As String
    <XmlAttribute("clientid")> Public Property clientid() As String
    Public Property ballColor As ballColor

    Public Sub New()
        ballColor = New ballColor
    End Sub

End Class

<Serializable>
Public Class ballColor
    <XmlText> Public Property ballColor As String
    <XmlAttribute("transactionid")> Public Property transactionid As String

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your ballColor class to this:

```
Public Class ballColor

    <XmlAttribute("transactionid")> 
    Public Property transactionid As String   

    <XmlText> 
    Public Property Value As String
End Class
```

This will store attribute `transactionid` value in `ballcolor.transactionid` and `ballcolor` value in `ballcolor.value` field

Change Main Ball class

```
Public Class Ball
  Public Property Name As String
    Public Property radius As Double
    Public Property PowerLevel As String
    Public Property RandomProp As String
    <XmlAttribute("clientid")> Public Property clientid() As String
    Public Property _ballColor As ballColor
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But...I had to do Value as (List of String) because it was throwing an error when i was creating my XmlSerializer object if I didnt. When I debug I no longer have my 'White' value that should be in ballColor (now called Value) and the transactionid is still 'nothing' :(

Comment: Thank you so much rs. You and Icidis both gave me the same solution. I'm going to give the answer to Icidis though because I saw his first and you have about 7400 more points than he does. Thanks again though!